# Is this a deliberate Naruto reference in Ben 10?

Tags: character, reference, naruto, ben-10

In the end of *Ben 10* episode 13th, we see town is back to normal and we see old man with three grand children:

[image]

But this three kid appear very similar to *Team Ebisu* from *Naruto*:

[image]

Even Konohamaru used to wear the goggles over his head

[image]

Is it just a coincidence or deliberate attempt to reference Naruto? Official wording will be more appreciated.

Comment: It certainly seems like it may be a deliberate reference to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there has been a subject of discussion among various videos I "unearthed" wherein they talked about the Naruto reference

**Examples:**

Also apparently **Maria Isabel Martiñón Fernández** was the voice actress for Ben in the localized Latin version who is also the voice actress for Naruto. [1](http://es.doblaje.wikia.com/wiki/Isabel_Marti%C3%B1%C3%B3n)

So this could just be another case of paying homage to one of the fandoms! :D